# Laravel and Passport Authentication via HTTPonlycookies

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, oauth

I am new to laravel and trying to do a simple Authentication project using the laravel/passport package provided by the laravel team and I have no problem with sending the token via a httponly cookie and receiving it from a frontend framework Vuejs. I am able to get the authentication working by storing the token into a localstorage on the browser but all the blogs and documentations I have read suggest not to use localstorage for storing a jwt token and most of them suggest to use httponly cookie because it is not accessible from javascript.

and for my layers of authentication use

1. a proxyRequest util class
2. an Authcontroller
3. I do not use the default User model I have a person model
4. I have a Cors middleware for allowing requests

#### proxyRequest class

```
<?php

 namespace App\Utilities;
 // use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class ProxyRequest {
public function grantPasswordToken(string $email, string $password)
{
    $params = [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => $email,
        'password' => $password,
    ];

    return $this->makePostRequest($params);
}

public function refreshAccessToken()
{
    $refreshToken = request()->cookie('refresh_token');

    abort_unless($refreshToken, 403, 'Your refresh token is expired.');

    $params = [
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
    ];

    return $this->makePostRequest($params);
}

protected function makePostRequest(array $params)
{
    $params = array_merge([
        'client_id' => config('services.passport.password_client_id'),
        'client_secret' => config('services.passport.password_client_secret'),
        'scope' => '',
    ], $params);

    $proxy = \Request::create('oauth/token', 'post', $params);
    $resp = json_decode(app()->handle($proxy)->getContent());

    $this->setHttpOnlyCookie($resp->refresh_token);

    return app()->handle($proxy)->getContent();
    return $resp;
}

  protected function setHttpOnlyCookie(string $refreshToken)
  {
    cookie()->queue(
        'refresh_token',
        $refreshToken,
        14400, // 10 days
        null,
        null,
        false,
        true // httponly
    );
  }
}
```

#### Authcontroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Person;
// use App\Person;
// use App\Person;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Cookie;
use App\Utilities\ProxyRequest;

class AuthController extends Controller
{


protected $proxy;

public function __construct(ProxyRequest $proxy)
{
    $this->proxy = $proxy;
}

public function user(Request $request)
{   
    if (Auth::guard('api')->check()) {
        return $request->user('api');
    }
    
    return "not auth";
}
public function register(Request $request)
{
    // $this->validate(request(), [
    //     'name' => 'required',
    //     'email' => 'required|email',
    //     'password' => 'required',
    // ]);

    $user = Person::create([
        'f_name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);

    $resp = $this->proxy->grantPasswordToken(
        $user->email,
        $request->password
    );

    // return response([
    //     'token' => $resp->access_token,
    //     'expiresIn' => $resp->expires_in,
    //     'message' => 'Your account has been created',
    // ], 201);
    return response()->json($resp);
}


public function check() {
    return "Authenticated";
}

public function refreshToken()
{
    $resp = $this->proxy->refreshAccessToken();

    return response([
        'token' => $resp->access_token,
        'expiresIn' => $resp->expires_in,
        'message' => 'Token has been refreshed.',
    ], 200);
}
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $token = $request->user()->token();
    $token->delete();

    // remove the httponly cookie
    cookie()->queue(cookie()->forget('refresh_token'));

    return response([
        'message' => 'You have been successfully logged out',
    ], 200);
        return $request->all();
}
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $user = Person::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    abort_unless($user, 404, 'User not found.');
    abort_unless(
        Hash::check($request->password, $user->password),
        403,
        'Password or mail address not correct.'
    );

    $resp = $this->proxy->grantPasswordToken($user->email, $request->password);
   
    return response([
        'token' => $resp->access_token,
        'expiresIn' => $resp->expires_in,
        'message' => 'You have been logged in',
    ], 200);
}


}
```

### routes

````
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::post('register', 'Api\AuthController@register')->name('register');
    Route::post('login', 'Api\AuthController@login')->name('login');
    Route::post('refresh-token', 'Api\AuthController@refreshToken')->name('refreshToken');
}); 

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::post('logout', 'Api\AuthController@logout')->name('logout');
});```
````

### middlewares

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\addCookieToHeader::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,

];
```

when I hit the login and register routes I am able to generate a token and could find it in my chrome (Application -> cookies with the name refresh token) but if I try to logout
i just get a response that says {message: "UnAuthenticated"} with a 401 error.

I couldnt find anything regarding this on the internet.

Comment: Is your front-end on the same domain add the API? In that case you should use the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware. Very helpful, does everything you need behind the scenes.

Comment: as I told you above I am new to laravel and could you explain what CreateFreshApiToken  does and how it works. And yes my frontend is on the same domain thank you

Comment: Sure. But if you are new to Laravel, the first thing you need to do is read the docs over and over again until you know where to find answers. Really, please don't take this negatively, reading the docs is essential. You'll find your answer here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript